# Format Date inside jQuery datatable

Tags: datatables, date-formatting

I am using jQuery datatables to display sms statistics on my web app, the datatable is used for ease of paging, search and sorting functionalities which works fine. However ene of the columns on the data table is a date,here is my action method that returns the json object

```
 public ActionResult LoadStatistics(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        //jQueryDataTableParamModel param = new jQueryDataTableParamModel();
        var allStats = _dbManager.GetSMSStatitistics();
        var filteredStats = allStats;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(param.sSearch))
        {
            filteredStats = filteredStats.Where(x => x.StaffNameF.Contains(param.sSearch, false)
                                            || x.StaffNameS.Contains(param.sSearch, false)
                                            || x.SiteID.Contains(param.sSearch, false)).ToList();
        }
        return Json(new
        {
            iTotalRecords = allStats.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredStats.Count(),
            aaData = filteredStats
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now in the view I have the following piece of code,to load data into my table,

```
@section scripts
```

{

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#statsTable').dataTable({
            bProcessing: true,
            bServerSide: false,
            bPaginate: true,
            sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("LoadStatistics", "Statistics")',
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "aTargets": [0], "mData": 'StaffNameF' },
                { "aTargets": [1], "mData": 'StaffNameS' },
                { "aTargets": [2], "mData": 'StaffEmail', "sWidth": "300px" },
                { "aTargets": [3], "mData": 'SiteID' },
                { "aTargets": [4], "mData": 'DateTimeIn', "sWidth": "300px", "sFormat": "dd/MM/YYYY" },
                { "aTargets": [5], "mData": 'CellNumber' }]
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is working fine for all the columns, except the date which displays something like this "/Date(1488924000000)/". I am assuming this is the date but it just needs formatting, how can I achieve this, I have tried "sFormat": "dd/MM/YYYY" but no luck, I have no clue how to do this inside the table.

Comment: Have a look at `Column rendering` (https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) and prehaps use Moment.js (http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json does not have a standard format for Dates.
You can either return the date as a string from the server or use datatables column rendering to parse and format the date clientside.

Returning the date as a formatted string from the server side:

```
return Json(new
{
     iTotalRecords = allStats.Count(),
     iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredStats.Count(),
     aaData = filteredStats.Select(x => new { 
        StaffNameF = x.StaffNameF, 
        StaffNameS = x.StaffNameS, 
        StaffEmail = x.StaffEmail, 
        SiteID = x.SiteID,
        DateTimeIn = x.DateTimeIn.ToString("dd/MM/YYYY"),
        CellNumber = x.CellNumber })
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Or formatting on the client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#statsTable').dataTable({
            bProcessing: true,
            bServerSide: false,
            bPaginate: true,
            sAjaxSource: '@Url.Action("LoadStatistics", "Statistics")',
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "aTargets": [0], "mData": 'StaffNameF' },
                { "aTargets": [1], "mData": 'StaffNameS' },
                { "aTargets": [2], "mData": 'StaffEmail', "sWidth": "300px" },
                { "aTargets": [3], "mData": 'SiteID' },
                { "aTargets": [4], "mData": 'DateTimeIn', "sWidth": "300px", "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                    var d = new Date();
                    d.setTime(1245398693390);
                    return d.getDate() + "/"+  (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear();
                },
                { "aTargets": [5], "mData": 'CellNumber' }]
        });
    });

</script>
```